# Google+ api search

Tags: search, google-api, google-plus

Please note that I have went through the entire documentation of google+. I can't find a way to specify `until` or `since` in search query. Basically I want to retrieve 10 posts per day for the last seven days.
Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

The Google+ [activity search API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) does not support limiting results by date range.

You might be able to work around this with some server side processing, though. You could search for activities using the `recent` order and page back through the results until posts are 7 days old. Once you have a local repository of posts, you can arbitrarily pick 10 for each day.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) but this wont work for me as the time required to retrieve 7 days old post is pretty high for my application. I dont have enough reputation otherwise I would have up voted your answer